# JMSSerializer and FOSRestBundle - Annotations not working. "Does not exist"

Tags: php, symfony, data-annotations, fosrestbundle, jmsserializerbundle

I am trying to use ExclusionPolicy however I keep getting an "Annotation does not exist, or could not be auto-loaded" error.

Here is the exact error being thrown out:

> [Semantical Error] The annotation
>   "@JMS\SerializerBundle\Annotation\ExclusionPolicy" in class
>   Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Attributes does not exist, or could not be
>   auto-loaded.

My code is as follows:

```
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints;
use JMS\SerializerBundle\Annotation\ExclusionPolicy;
use JMS\SerializerBundle\Annotation\Expose;

/**
 * Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Attributes
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\AttributesRepository")
 * 
 * @ExclusionPolicy("all")
 */
class Attributes
{
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

your problem is caused by using the wrong namespace.

Instead of:

```
use JMS\SerializerBundle\Annotation\ExclusionPolicy;
use JMS\SerializerBundle\Annotation\Expose;
```

It should be:

```
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\ExclusionPolicy;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\Expose;
```

Notice "Bundle" is gone. In [Ver 0.11](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSerializerBundle/blob/master/UPGRADING.md#upgrading-from-010-to-011) it was extracted to its own repository.

The changelog is as follows:

> - **Namespace Changes**
>
> The core library has been extracted to a dedicated repository
>   `schmittjoh/serializer` to make it easier re-usable in any kind of PHP
>   project, not only in Symfony2 projects. This results in several
>   namespace changes. You can adjust your projects by performing these
>   replacements (in order):
>
> - JMS\SerializerBundle\Serializer -> JMS\Serializer
> - JMS\SerializerBundle -> JMS\Serializer
> - JMS\Serializer\DependencyInjection -> JMS\SerializerBundle\DependencyInjection
> - **Dependency Changes**
>
> You might need to increase versions of jms/di-extra-bundle, and also
>   jms/security-extra-bundle depending on your stability settings.
>   Sometimes it is also necessary to run a composer update twice because
>   of a bug in composer's solving algorithm.